# Creating tag names for installed fonts and displaying font name in font style

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, fonts

I have written this code to get a list of installed fonts on my system, which should then create a text widget with all the fonts displayed. However, I find that some of the fonts in the list are named but not displayed correctly. They are not 'clickable' so I guess that a tag has not been created for that item. Anyone have an idea why this would be?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font



def on_click(event):

    fontname=display.index('@{},{}'.format(event.x,event.y))

    print (display.tag_names(fontname))
    return None


root = Tk()

fonts=list(font.families())
fonts.sort()

display = Text(root)
display.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES, side=LEFT)

scroll = Scrollbar(root)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y, expand=NO)

scroll.configure(command=display.yview)
display.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)

for item in fonts:
    i=fonts.index(item)
    i+=1
    i=str(i)
    display.tag_add  (item,  ('{}.0'.format(i))  ,END)

    display.tag_config(item,font=(item,25,'normal'))


    display.tag_bind(item,'<Double-1>',on_click)

    display.insert(END, (item +'\n'),(item))


root.mainloop()
```

my output for example `'Arial Black'` is `('Arial', 'Black')`
but for 'Comic Sans MS' I get nothing. By passing `'font=(item,15,'normal)` spaces should not be an issue or did I misread that? or could it be the way the font titles are formatted in the font file? This is all new to me the last time I did any coding it was on a zx81

Comment: are you observing that every item that isn't "clickable" has a space in the name?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the tags given for the `insert` statement needs to be a list. You are using `(item)` which, I'm guessing, you think is a one-item tuple. It is not a tuple, it's just a string expression. For it to be a tuple it needs a comma (eg: `(item,)`).

Thus, what is getting passed to the widget is something like `"DejaVu Sans Mono"`. The underlying tcl interpreter sees this as a list of three tags: `"DejaVu"`, `"Sans"`, and `"Mono"`.

To pass a proper list, either use brackets or include a comma to change your expression into a tuple.

Notice in the following example, the command at the end of `(item,)`.

```
display.insert(END, (("%s: " % i) + item +'\n'),(item,))
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix just the little comma after item did the job. Now I have to go off and learn why it did that.